# Spark Mongo connector how to verify read preferences

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am using spark mongo connector(https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/). There are couple of things i want to verfiy if the read config settings that i am using are correct on not.. I am using a read config

```
val courseReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map(
  "uri" -> "mongodb://ip:port/db.collection?read_preference=Primary([{\"cloudType\" : \"aws\",\"dataCenter\" : \"us-east-1\"}])",
  "partitionerOptions.shardkey" -> "key",
  "partitioner" -> "MongoShardedPartitioner"
 ))
```

The other thing is i am making the read query to a Mongos server, i want to know wether the query is then processed by mongos and it sends the results back to spark or wether the spark after geting the network topology from Mongos , makes request to individual mongo servrers/primary/secondary to read the data..

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is no longer correct to set the ReadPreference you need to set the `readPreference.name` and the `readPreference.tags` eg:

```
val courseReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map(
  "uri" -> "mongodb://ip:port/db.collection"
  "readPreference.name"="primary",
  "readPreference.tags"="""[{"cloudType" : "aws", "dataCenter" : "us-east-1"}]""",
  "partitionerOptions.shardkey" -> "key",
  "partitioner" -> "MongoShardedPartitioner"
))
```

> I want to know whether the query is then processed by mongos and it sends the results back to spark or whether the spark after getting the network topology from Mongos

Partitioning happens first, then for each partition the Spark Worker will connect to the URI and get its section of results to work on. This means *any* connections from the Workers to Mongo will be done via one of the MongoS's supplied in the URI. If you only supply one then that MongoS will be used by all the Spark Workers, so for redundancy and performance purposes you should supply more than one. Theres a little more information in the "[How can I achieve data locality?](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/faq/#how-can-i-achieve-data-locality)" section in the documentation.  The Mongo Spark Connector will not connect directly to the MongoD on the shard as that risks incorrect information being returned to the user.

Comment: Ross can you please elaborate a little more.. if i have given the mongos server in URI , will all the spark workers connect to mongos for result or will the connect to mongo data nodes for result? Is there any documentation i can read from.Thanks.

Comment: @PrashantVerma I edited my answer to include answers to your questions.